# JS - text value of tag - when tag is string

Tags: javascript, regex, dom

How can I get text value of a tag when tag is stored as string?

```
var value = "<div>teeext</div>";
```

tag can be anything, its attributes may contain ">" string as well, regexp can be dangerous - also text value itself can be another tag.

Comment: what do you mean when you say "when tag is stored as string" ? also, what have you tried?

Comment: The whole html element is stored in a variable - as example shows.

Comment: please read: http://whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: i tried regexp (as its mentioend in the question as well).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a dummy element:

```
var value = "<div>teeext</div>";

var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = value;

var text = div.innerText || div.textContent;
```

Comment: is it possible to have the result without manipulating the document?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you're trying to strip tags.. In that case you can do it like this:

```
originalString = "<div>teeext</div>";
var value = originalString.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
```

Test it out. If there are any exceptions which you need to handle, then just comment here and I'll try to help you further.

Edit for multiple tags:

```
originalString = "<div>teeext</div>";
outputString = originalString;
while (outputString.indexOf(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig) !== -1){
    outputString = outputString.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
    }
value = outputString;
```

Haven't tested it, but you get the point ;)

Comment: for this: "<div><div>teeext</div></div>": I would like to see this: "<div>teeext</div>"

Comment: You would like to see that or you would see that? Are you trying to strip all the tags or not?

Answer (score 0):

Using just javascript:

```
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    var value = "<div>teeext</div>";
    div.innerHTML = value; 
    var element = div.firstChild

    console.log(element.innerHTML); //this the stuff in the tag
```

Using jquery:

```
$(value).html();
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this help as a starter?

```
function getText(tagString) {
    var firstOpenTag = tagString.indexOf(">"),
        lastCloseTag = tagString.lastIndexOf("</"),
        substrLength;

    if (firstOpenTag == -1 || lastCloseTag == -1) {
        return tagString;
    }

    substrLength = (tagString.length - firstOpenTag) - (tagString.length - lastCloseTag) - 1;
    return tagString.substr(firstOpenTag + 1, substrLength);
}

var value = "<div>teeext</div>";

console.log(getText(value));

var moreTags = "<div><ul><li>Text</li></ul></div>",
    returnValue = moreTags,
    prevReturnValue = "";

while (returnValue !== prevReturnValue) {
    prevReturnValue = returnValue;
    returnValue = getText(returnValue);
}

console.log(returnValue);
```